# Intent not working. When i click Sign In it is going to MainActivity.java instead of going to Home.java

Tags: java, android

Unable to Point Out whats going wrong here. Target SDK- 28, Android Studio- 3.3.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignIn.this);
                mDialog.setMessage("Please wait....");
                mDialog.show();

                table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.child(edtPhn.getText().toString()).exists()) {


                            mDialog.dismiss();

                            User user = dataSnapshot.child(edtPhn.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
                                if (user.getPassword().equals(edtPass.getText().toString()))
                                    {
                                        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(SignIn.this, Home.class);
                                        Common.currentUser = user;
                                        startActivity(homeIntent);
                                        finish();
                                    } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Invalid Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "User not Exist in database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
```

no error Still whats happening. my intent is not going to home.java as it has list view and firebaseui.

Answer (score 0):

A different code is being executed that is directing to your main activity.
Try to comment your code below and see if it still directs you to your MainClass.
If it does just search for the words MainActivity.class in your code and try to see if it is being called when you press Sign.

```
                            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(SignIn.this, Home.class);
                            Common.currentUser = user;
                            startActivity(homeIntent);
                            finish();
```

Comment: i spoted the problem. the problem was in the "home.class" 's layout. and thank you martin for your help. wish u luck in all your future work also.